# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode' python mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I'm having this error AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode' and here is the part of my code. can you please help me

```
def add_customer():
    sql_command = """INSERT INTO customer (first_name, last_name, zipcode, price_paid, email, address_1, address_2, city, state_1, country, phone, payment_method, discount_code) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""",
    values = (first_name_box.get(), last_name_box.get(), zipcode_box.get(), price_paid_box.get(), email_box.get(), address_1_box.get(),address_2_box.get(),city_box.get(),state_1_box.get(), country_box.get(),phone_box.get(),payment_method_box.get(), discount_code_box.get()),
    my_cursor.execute(sql_command, values)

    mydb.commit()
    creat_field()
```

Comment: Can you past the full error :)

Comment: I think it's due to the "," line 2 and 3. remove this one or try my_cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO customer (first_name, ...) VALUES (?, ...)""", values)

Comment: GuiEpi spottet it nicely. Remove the comma at the end of your line. `a=1,` is equivalent to `a=(1,)` a tuple.

Comment: thank you but none of them work:(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.